# Java: Simple JSON Array throws "org.json.JSONException: No value for ..."

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, eclipse

This seems really straightforward but I can't get around this exception. I'm using Eclipse ADT and working on a basic Android project. Here's the JSON I'm parsing:

```
{
    "activated": 1,
    "message": [
        {
            "type": "dialog",
            "name": "testdialog01",
            "list": [
                "Truck 001",
                "Truck 002",
                "Truck 003",
                "Truck 004",
                "Truck 006"
            ],
            "heading": "Which truck are you currently driving?",
            "id": 17
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's the code I'm parsing it with:

```
JSONObject jsonRes = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray msgs = jsonRes.getJSONArray("message");

for (int i=0; i<msgs.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject jsonObj = msgs.getJSONObject(i);

    String type = jsonObj.getString("type");
    String diaName = jsonObj.getString("name");
    String diaHeading = jsonObj.getString("heading");

    JSONArray diaList = jsonRes.getJSONArray("list"); //exception thrown
}
```

The "list" portion of the JSON is a valid JSONArray. Debugger confirms this. I get a "No value for list" JSONException when I hit getJSONArray line above. What gives? The top level "message" array is similar, only its values are wrapped in curly braces whereas "list" is just an array of strings. I tested this JSON at jsonlint.com and it's valid, but maybe just isn't agreeable with the standard org.json API? I don't control the incoming JSON so I'm not able to easily test this theory myself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have typo: try to change `jsonRes.getJSONArray("list");` to `jsonObj.getJSONArray("list");`

Comment: Oh man...that's embarrassing. Haha! I've been staring at that stupid thing for 20 minutes, wondering WTF!? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your line:

```
JSONArray diaList = jsonRes.getJSONArray("list"); //exception thrown
```

Should be:

```
JSONArray diaList = jsonObj.getJSONArray("list"); //all good!
```